# Angular 6 error: the data which I am getting from api is in the string format how to parse?

Tags: json, angular, angular6

hi want to show the data from my api to my frontend (Angular 6) I am using HttpClient method from angular 6 I am new to angular
the data which I am getting from api is in the string format, I need to parse, below is the response image

[image: the data which I am getting from api is in the string format, I need to parse, below is the response image]

this is model.ts

```
export interface Events {

IE_Incident_Start_Time: string;
IE_Start_time: string;
Title: string;
IE_Start_By: string;
Domain: string;
Impact: string;
IE_BU_Description: string;
}
```

this is component

```
enter code here
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Incident } from '../../shared/incidents.model';
import { DataStorageService } from '../../shared/data-storage.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-active-incident',
templateUrl: './active-incident.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./active-incident.component.css']
})
export class ActiveIncidentComponent implements OnInit {

incidents: Events[];

constructor(private router: Router, private dataStorageService: 
DataStorageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.dataStorageService.getIncidents()
.subscribe(
(data: Events[]) => this.incidents = data,
(err: any) => console.log(err),
() => console.log('All done getting incidents')
);
}
```

this is service

```
enter code here
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Incident } from './incidents.model';

@Injectable()
export class DataStorageService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getIncidents(): Observable<Events[]> {
console.log('Getting all incidents from server');
return this.http.get<Events[]> 
('api/url');
}
}
```

html view

```
enter code here
<div class="card" *ngFor="let incident of incidents.Events">
<div class="card-header">
<span class="badge badge-danger"></span>{{incident.Title}}
<span class="badge badge-danger"></span>{{incident.Incident_Status}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best way would be to fix your API so that it returns JSON instead of that format that you can't parse.

Comment: Thank you Nizet, But is there a way in angular 6 HttpClient where I can Parse the result which I am getting now?

Comment: You can do anything you want. Byut why dod you choose this format if you don't know how to parse it?

Comment: Because the format which I am getting is the best, the api team could give me, now i need to convert it to object..

Comment: Well, you'll need a clear specification of that format, and you'll need to write a parser from it (unless it's some sort of standard format for which a parser already exists).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it this way.

```
    this.dataStorageService.getIncidents().subscribe((data: Events[]) =>{
    data.foreach(()=>{
 this.incidents.push(JSON.parse(data));
       })

    },
    (err: any) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('All done getting incidents')
    );
```

Comment: Hi thankyou but I am getting error saying,  Property 'foreach' does not exist on type 'Event'.

Comment: sorry but I am getting same error Property 'foreach' does not exist on type 'Events[]'

Comment: can you verify data is array? or object?

Comment: its an object, I have to parse, But I don't know how to parse in angular 6, while using httpClient

Comment: Hi thank you for you support,  I had tried this before and got this error, rror TS2345: Argument of type 'Events[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. and in console i get ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: you got an object instead of an array. so, you need to convert it first into array

Answer (score 0):

you can use the way as well

```
return this.dataStorageService.getIncidents()
      .pipe(
        map(jsonObj => Object.assign(new Events(), jsonObj),
        catchError(error => console.log('Error!'))
      );
```